# Mam vs Ma'am difference

Tags: differences, pronunciation, vocabulary, forms-of-address

Is Mam slowly becoming a substitute for Ma'am as a lot of people don't know the difference between the two.

Comment: Can you please be more specific? Mam, except in Ireland (I think) where it could stand for  "mum", and Ma'am are not commonly used in the UK. Ma'am is a more commonly heard in the Southern States of the US. Could you please say what the difference is between them, and which English dialect you are referring to. Maybe you're talking about Indian English? Thanks.

Comment: Well, I'm not an expert of even Indian English let alone other dialects. When I check the meaning of Mam on Google, it tells me that it's an informal word for mother. But I've seen several people, using it as a contraction of the word Madam for which we've got Ma'am.

Comment: You've seen it where? Written by whom? How do you know that a lot of people don't know the difference? You need to supply evidence and a couple of citations.

Comment: There are two separate issues here - pronunciation and orthography. In practice, most people today (certainly, in the UK) use the same "short A" pronunciation for the honorific (contracted *Madam*) as the regional / dialectal diminutive *(Mam = Mum = Mother)*. Using the "long A" (pronounced *Marm, Mahm*) is generally perceived as a dated "pseudo-formal" affectation (such as might have been used by butlers and other house servants in a bygone age).

Comment: @FumbleFingers I use and I am accustomed to the "ar" sound in ma'am, I'm hardly prehistoric. There's also the American English "ma'am" term.

Comment: Pardon me for being a bit naive and narrow in my perspective, but what I meant by 'a lot of people' was the people I usually interact with(Indians). Honestly I didn't know about the difference in the pronunciation of both words. I checked in the 2 dictionaries I use (vocabulary.com and one other) and honestly I couldn't make out the difference. Maybe it's quite subtle.

Comment: @Vishal: I wouldn't say the pronunciation difference is "subtle". There's a huge difference between "short A" as in ***dam, Mam*** and "long A" as in ***farm, Ma'am***).

Comment: @FumbleFingers You mean short-a like in *ham* versus long-a like in *face*, right? I don't understand those other ones like in *run* or *wrong*. I thought ER2 specifically said that "*Ma'am* should rhyme with *ham*" in Her English. After all, she's neither your mother nor a chrysanthemum, eh now! ;-}

Comment: That's interesting. Are you sure Ma'am is pronounced in the same way as 'farm'? Coz I've never heard it being pronounced in that way(even in the dictionary as well). If this was the case then we Indians have been using the wrong word while greeting the teachers everyday in class because the way we pronounced Ma'am was similar to 'Dam'

Comment: @tchrist: I suppose there might be some Americans for whom the vowel in *Ma'am* rhymes with that in *face*, but I've never heard that from a Brit. Like I said, the "affected, dated" long A I'm talking about is the one in *farm* (but obviously no /r/, since we Brits have no truck with "rhoticism" such as occurs in various AmE accents).

Comment: From Jane Eyre: *Oh, yes, **marm**, he's alive!* And [here are over 3600 written instances](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22yes+marm%22) with ***marm*** instead of ***madam / ma'am***. Plus [81 instances of ***Yes Mahm***](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22yes+mahm%22) to prove the point.

Comment: @FumbleFingers This is the problem inherent to calling sounds short-this and long-that when those terms map to utterly different sounds depending on who says it. I'd rather use IPA: *ma’am* is /mæm/ with the TRAP vowel from *ham*; the verb *maim* is /meɪm/ with the FACE vowel; *(chrysanthe)mum* is /mʌm/ with the STRUT vowel like in *run* or unstressed in *about*; and *Khan* is /kɑn/ whether Kubla or Genghis. Most but not all Americans have *Mom* as /mɑm/ and so like *Khan* — **not** /mɔm/ as in *wrong* or *cloth* or *thought* or *palm*.

Comment: This discussion is getting more and more interesting for me. I hadn't even read/heard 'marm' before! On checking this word quickly on Google I found that it's a variant spelling of Ma'am. I see that you guys have been pronouncing Ma'am in the same way as 'Farm', although I'm still not convinced if it's correct (I've got dictionaries supporting my Indian way of pronouncing Ma'am which is a lot closer to ham/Mam than Mum/Marm/farm.

Comment: @Vishal: Will you *please* stop thinking in terms of "correct / incorrect"! If that meant anything at all, the only correct form would be ***Madam***. Otherwise it's just a regional / social status / age-related personal choice.

Comment: @FumbleFingers When I had posted this question what I had meant was that, in written English, I see a lot of people around me, using Mam when they intended to use Ma'am(this, as I had pointed earlier can also be due to the fact that to us Indians both the words have same pronunciation). I understand that the pronunciation changes with geography but pronouncing Ma'am in a similar way as 'Farm' is a huge difference for me(bringing the sound of 'r' into Ma'am makes no sense to me despite the fact that you mentioned the variant spelling, Marm(I'm thankful to you for teaching me a new word).

Comment: You need to say this IN your question, not in comments. Please edit your question and add details and clarifications. There will be few users who will want to wade through so many spurious comments.

Comment: @Vishal That’s _marm_ as it would be pronounced in non-rhotic British English, i.e., /mɑːm/. The r is not actually pronounced, it’s only there to show that the vowel is /ɑː/ (as in _father_), not /a/ (as in _ham_).

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet What happened to your /æ/ vowel there in /hæm/ for *ham*? Are you making some phonemic distinction between /ɑ/ and /a/ and /æ/?? I thought no dialect of English phonemically distinguished between low unrounded vowels over the front–back axis. Is this the ultimate explanation behind the perplexing mystery of why Americans hear Brits saying *macho* as though it were /ˈmæt͡ʃoʊ̯/ instead of as /ˈmɑt͡ʃoʊ̯/ the way we say it? Are we hearing them say front vowels so class it as the /æ/ phoneme and they’re not actually saying that because they only have a front not a back low vowel?

Comment: @tchrist No, that was just a typo—it was meant to be /æ/. ODO and OED write /a/ for the BrE vowel and /æ/ for the American one, but as archephonemes representing lexical set vowels, it makes no sense to distinguish them; they represent the same phoneme, just based on different dialectal allophones.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet Ah ok thanks then. I don't understand why the OED does that. It’s confusing. At least they’ve fixed it so that they write /ɛ/ now for DRESS.

Comment: @tchrist I think they do it because their pronunciation guides are somewhere between phonemic and phonetic, but closer to the phonetic end of the spectrum. Generally speaking, BrE /æ/ is more open and less front than AmE /æ/, so if you’re going to more-or-less-phonetically write out separate BrE and AmE pronunciations, it’s not entirely illogical to write them accordingly. Not really what you’d call _necessary_ either, though.

Answer (score 3):

Ma'am is used in UK in the armed forces and the police when a junior addresses a female superior officer. It is also used to address Her Majesty the Queen.

Mam is used for "mum" in Yorkshire (see Alan Bennett's diaries, for example).

To answer the direct question: I have seen no evidence of Mam replacing Ma'am, nor, until seeing this Question, had I heard of such a possibility.

Comment: The pronunciation of these two terms are quite different though, it's hard to see how the two can get mixed up as the OP suggests. I don't think anyone would greet  Queen Elizabeth as "Mam".

Comment: @Mari-Lou A: Per my comment above, that's not true. The "short A" version is becoming increasingly common, and my guess would be that's the one the Queen hears most when she's meeting her public these days.

Comment: When you are going to meet the Queen you are told firmly that Ma'am rhymes with Mam. That is the pronunciation used in the police, and I heard it only yesterday from a female officer in the US Navy.

Comment: @JeremyC "Rhymes with *ham*."

Comment: In most US dialects, Mam and Ma'am would be said exactly the same way (rhyming with Sam, ham, lamb). I *suspect* even non-rhotic US speakers would say both more-or-less this way, without sticking an r sound in. On the other hand, reading that Mam and Mum have the same pronunciation is completely bumfuzzling.

Comment: @JeremyC : Can you provide anything to back up that assertion? I find it unlikely that the Palace would give any such guidance. Dunno if royal.co.uk is an officially-sanctioned website, but they quite correctly point out that [There are no obligatory codes of behaviour when meeting The Queen or a member of the Royal Family.](https://www.royal.uk/greeting-member-royal-family) And I know for sure the Palace have no position regarding whether women should curtsey before the queen. Some people just like to do it, is all.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Montague-Smith (Ed.),Debrett's Correct Form, Kelly's Directories 1971: "Verbal Address. 'Your Majesty' for the first time. Subsequently 'Ma'am'. This should always rhyme with Pam. Pronunciation to rhyme with Palm is never used, nor has this been so for some generations."

Comment: and yet 'Ms'  is in here too.

Comment: According to a quick dictionary search, it seems that "mam" meaning "ma'am" is only used in the US.

Comment: @JeremyC : It turns out my link *is* the official Palace site. And I see that elsewhere on the site they say *On presentation to The Queen, the correct formal address is 'Your Majesty' and subsequently 'Ma'am,' pronounced with a short 'a,' as in 'jam'.* So in the end I guess they do have an opinion - it's just not a matter of *requirement*.  I seem to recall this being exploited for humour in the movie *The Queen*, where Tony Blair supposedly needed to be coached on how to address HM.

Comment: @FumbleFingers are you now saying that Ma'am is pronounced similarly as Mam?

Comment: @VishalSharma I have no idea what this purported **Mam* word is; I think it does not exist.

Comment: @Vishal Sharma: By most people today, yes. But the *orthography* isn't likely to change in most written contexts, unless the author has some special reason to want to call attention to the way some specific person pronounces it (both pronunciations are "valid" and in use; it's just that the short A version is much more common today than it was even a generation ago).

Comment: ...also note that there are still plenty of people who if they were serving behind a counter would address the customer as ***Mam***, but if they were being introduced to the Queen they'd say ***Ma'am = Marm***. Usage in this area is fluid, and for the "royal" context many people are likely to be guided by what they see/hear in period dramas and such, because they're not likely to know and speak with people who *actually* routinely address the Queen.

Comment: I may be conflating different dialectal features, but to me _mam_, _ma’am_, and _marm_ are all distinct. _Mam_ (meaning ‘mother’) has a short open front vowel: [mam]. _Ma’am_ (a courteous form of address to any woman) rhymes with _ham_, having a semi-long open or mid-open front vowel: [maˑm ~ mæˑm]. _Marm_ (a form of address to a female superior in the police or armed forces, as well as to the Queen, royal recommendations notwithstanding) rhymes with _palm_, having a long open, unrounded back vowel: [mɑːm]. They are three distinct words to me, though I’d not usually **write** _marm_.

Comment: @tchrist try a dictionary

Comment: @Janus Bahs Jacquet maybe you associate with different police and military people from me. I have never heard any of those I meet use Marm. It is also news to me, a Southern English RP speaker, that ham, pam, jam, Mam have different pronunciations.

Comment: @JeremyC I don’t really associate with any of them—I should perhaps have been more specific and said that _marm_, apart from being what I’d call the Queen if I ever met her and forgot that I’m supposed to call her _ma’am_, is a form of address to female superiors in the police or armed forces _in the tv shows which represent the only place I’ve ever actually encountered police/armed force employees addressing female superiors_. In [this _Lewis_ episode](http://www.dailymotion.com/video/x4v20ss) (33:50), for example.

Comment: @JeremyC As for _mam_ having a shorter vowel, I wouldn’t normally use the word at all except when in Ireland. I have no standard BrE pronunciation for the word at all—I would unfailingly say _mum_ instead—only an Irish English pronunciation. I’m not sure I’d ever use either of the other two words in an Irish setting, though, so while they are definitely three different lexemes with three different pronunciations to me, I’m not sure if I would ever be able to contrast all three in one and the same setting.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet Thanks for the Lewis link. Of course they are not real police officers.  I certainly don't know how all real police officers say the word but I used to see quite a few senior female police and I always heard the short form.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet The range of actual pronunciations that words like *man* and *ma’am* regularly take on throughout North America (and beyond) under **“/æ/ *raising”*** is extremely wide: *man* becomes any of  [mæn], [mæə̯n], [mæ̝ˑə̯n], [mɛə̯n], [mɛˑə̯n], [ˈmɛjən], [mɪə̯n], [meə̯n] depending on the region, speaker, and utterance. That’s part of why the title and question are so unclear and confusing, because it’s conflating spellings with phonemics with phonetics in a way that is impossible to guess how to disentangle as written.

Comment: @1006a  No-one said that Mam and Mum have the same pronunciation. 'Mam' is used for addressing one's mother in some parts of the British Isles instead of the more usual 'Mum'.

Answer (score 1):

"Ma'am" could be substituted for Miss or Missus if you were talking to a teacher/lecturer, whereas "Mam" is an informal and extremely casual way of saying mother.

"Mam" is commonly shortened to "Ma" in Ireland for referring to a mother, whereas "Ma'am" would never be used in any context here.